# Getting error "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined" on dynamically created vue instance

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I need to find a way to create dynamic component instances programmatically (instead of through a template).

Although I have found a solution (it seems), the naive way of just create a new vue-instance using `new Vue(..)` results in an error:

`Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined`.

This seems strange to me, since it should just be possible to do so afaik. I.e.: there's a template defined on the extended vue class.

Please see the code below, with 2 commented out ways that work, and the current (non commented out) code that doesn't work.

My contrived code:

```
  const HelloComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '<p>Welcome home!</p>'
  });

  const Home1 = {
    template: '<p>Welcome home!</p>'
  };

  const Home2 = {
    extends: HelloComponent
  };

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        // currentView: Home1 // does work
        // currentView: Home2 // does work
        currentView: new HelloComponent() //does NOT work. Why?
      };
    },
    template: '<component :is="currentView"></component>',
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in `component` component can accept a string, a component constructor, or a component definition object. `Vue.extends` creates a new component constructor function. To make your code work you should pass the constructor function itself, not the result of creating it.

```
currentView: HelloComponent
```

Essentially, the result of `new HelloComponent()` is not a component definition object or a component constructor function, it's a Vue instance.

Comment: It seems that with this solution, each time you do the above assignment `currentView: HelloComponent` , no new instance is created, which is what I want. `currentView: {extends: HelloComponent}` does work. Would you recommend this approach if having a new instance per assignment is needed?

Comment: @Geert-Jan Could you give me a little more information? I experimented in a codepen and each time currentView is set, it appears to create a new instance. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YZNbJe?editors=1011

Comment: See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PppPRY?editors=1011. Difference with your pen is that I want to load the same component (but a different instance), without first loading a different component. Use-case, say, multiple tabs, that on click each assign `currentView: TabPanel` but with different data attached.

Comment: @Geert-Jan In that pen, you aren't actually changing the value of currentView, just repetitively setting it to the same value, so nothing happens. If its the data that's changed, just change the data passed in through the props and the same HelloComponent will re-render the new data; not sure why it needs to be a new instance. In any case, if you truly need a new instance I don't see anything wrong with your {extends: HelloComponent} solution.

Comment: @Bert What about if the `HelloComponent` have some required props, how would you pass it?

Comment: @user2976753 props that you add to `<component />` will be passed to whatever component it *is* like so: `<component :is="currentView" :prop1="value1" :prop2="value2" />`.

Comment: Yep, but how pass props to `HelloComponent` before is passed to `:is`?

Comment: @user2976753 Why would you need to? Perhaps open a new question with your specific situation to explain.

Comment: Imagine this `this.$store.commit('modal/open', editUser)`, I need to pass a `user` object to `editView`, inside a modal I have `<component :is="RECEIVED VIEW"`, i've tested using `extend, new` but not look

Comment: @Bert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543567/how-pass-props-to-view-component-before-is-mounted-in-component-is-view

Comment: You can pass props to the dynamic component with `Vue.extend`. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2114#issuecomment-231129268